# Excel Formula: Range Between 2 Values = Text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do this in excel:

If Original Contract Value is between range of two numbers = Words Here for this example %:

```
=IF(AND(E8>1000,E8<1500000),"11.94%","11.94%"),IF(AND(E8>1500000,E8<7000000),"13.79","13.79"),IF(AND(E8>7000000,E8<20000000),"16.41%","16.41%")))
```

Range

```
1000-1,500,000   11.94%
1.5M-7M          13.79%
7M-20M           16.41%
```

I keep on getting an error message, can someone help me out?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Kym.  It may be helpful to provide the error message that you are receiving.  Is the error for all values?

Answer (score 1):

You've got too many options. Each IF must have one result for TRUE and one for FALSE. In this bit

```
=IF(AND(E8>1000,E8<1500000),"11.94%","11.94%")
```

you only need the first result if the statement evalutes to TRUE, if not you want to proceed to the next IF so the second 11.94% is redundant (erroneous).

Try this.

> =IF(AND(E8>1000,E8<1500000),11.94%,IF(AND(E8>1500000,E8<7000000),13.79%,IF(AND(E8>7000000,E8<20000000),16.41%,"???")))

You should add a result too if E8 >= 20000000 (where I have put ???) and you don't need the quote marks as you are inserting numbers, not strings.

---

However, a more efficient way using LOOKUPs is outlined [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/group-numbers-with-vlookup). This is particularly advantageous if you have many bands. In your example it's six of one and half a dozen of the other.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(E8,{1000,1500000,7000000}),11.94%,13.79%,16.41%)
```